# LabelFor incorrect when using AllowHtml

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I'm using MVC 5.2.2.0, .net 4.5.1 and I'm seeing some odd behavior.  I have a model like so:

```
public class Program
{
    // .... Other Properties 

    [Display(Name = "Courses Description")]
    [RichText]
    [AllowHtml]
    public string CoursesDescription { get; set; }

    // .... Other Properties
}
```

`RichText` is a custom attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class RichText : Attribute
{
    public RichText() { }
}
```

All it is used for is to tell the T4 template to add the wysi data-editor attribute to the `TextAreaFor` html helper.

My view has the following:

```
 <div class="form-group">
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CoursesDescription, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-sm-3" })
     <div class="col-sm-6">
         @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.CoursesDescription, 10, 20, new { @class = "form-control", data_editor = "wysi" })
         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CoursesDescription, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
     </div>
 </div>
```

With the AllowHtml attribute, the View renders like this:

[image: Incorrect Label]

However, if I modify the model by removing the AllowHtml attribute, the view renders correctly.

```
public class Program
{
    // .... Other Properties 

    [Display(Name = "Courses Description")]
    [RichText]
    public string CoursesDescription { get; set; }

    // .... Other Properties
}
```

[image: Correct Rendering]

It is also worth pointing out that removing the `RichText` attribute doesn't change anything, the View still ignores the `Display` attribute.

Any ideas why `AllowHtml` is interfering with `LabelFor`?

Comment: I assume you mean `[Display(Name = "Courses Description")]`? The `DescriptAttribute` dos not contain a property `Name`

Comment: @StephenMuecke, thanks, I typed incorrectly in my question.  Edit made.

Comment: Works fine for me. And refer this [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DsTLbv) to prove it. I suspect there must me some other issue in your code if this is not working

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I too can't duplicate with your DotNetFiddle...I've edited my post with more code and images.  See anything?

Comment: Makes no sense. All the `[AllowHtml]` does is set the `RequestValidationEnabled` property of `ModelMetadata` to `false`. It does not change the `DisplayName` property so there must be something else at play.

Comment: I agree...makes no sense...that's why I'm here, lol

Comment: Turns out my models project was using MVC 5.2.3.0, while my MVC Project was using MVC 5.2.2.0.  Making them both 5.2.2.0 fixed this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Digging deeper into this, I noticed that my MVC project was using MVC 5.2.2.0, but I had inadvertently installed MVC 5.2.3.0 for my models project.

Downgrading the models project to 5.2.2.0 fixed the problem.